# Multiplication of factorials with a step size

Tags: factorial

I am asking if there is a simple form involving the multiplication of factorials like the following,$$9! 14! 19! 24!$$
here the step size is 5. In general we have $$(n)!(n-k)!(n-2k)!(n-3k)!$$ Is there any simple form for this? Or at least a bound?

Comment: This is called the Q-Pochhammer Symbol or sometimes the q-factorial symbol which is used to notate this idea. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol